# Inaccurate positioning of overlays in Android's MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, xamarin.android, itemizedoverlay

I'm trying to create an Activity with MapView and ListView inside it. I use C# and MonoDroid.

Layout looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <app.MD.UI.PlacesMapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:apiKey="key" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/resultsTable" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My custom MapView class implements long press handler

```
private void HandleLongPress(MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
                // Finger has touched screen.
                longpressTimer = new Timer(LONGPRESS_THRESHOLD);
                longpressTimer.AutoReset = false;
                longpressTimer.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e_elapsed) {
                    GeoPoint longpressLocation = Projection.FromPixels((int)e.GetX(), (int)e.GetY());
                    if (OnLongPress != null) {
                        OnMapViewLongPressEventArgs args = new OnMapViewLongPressEventArgs();
                        args.location = longpressLocation;
                        OnLongPress(this, args);
                    }
                };

                longpressTimer.Start();

                lastMapCenter = MapCenter;
            }

            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Move) {
                if (!MapCenter.Equals(lastMapCenter)) {
                    longpressTimer.Stop();
                }

                lastMapCenter = MapCenter;
            }

            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up) {
                // User has removed finger from map.
                longpressTimer.Stop();
            }

            if (e.PointerCount > 1) {
                // This is a multitouch event, probably zooming.
                longpressTimer.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Activity method, which adds marker to the MapView

```
protected void AddPinToMap(GeoPoint location, string title, bool scrollTo, int zoom)
        {
            var pin = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.maps_pin);
            PinOverlay pinOverlay = new PinOverlay(pin, this);
            OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(location, title, "");
            pinOverlay.AddOverlay(item);
            mapView.Overlays.Clear();
            mapView.Overlays.Add(pinOverlay);

            if (scrollTo) {
                mapView.Controller.AnimateTo(location);
            }

            mapView.Controller.SetZoom(zoom);
        }
```

And this is my PinOverlay class

```
class PinOverlay : ItemizedOverlay
    {
        private List<OverlayItem> _items = new List<OverlayItem>();
        private Context _context;

        public PinOverlay(Drawable pin, Context context) : base(pin)
        {
            _context = context;
            BoundCenterBottom(pin);
            Populate();
        }

        protected override Java.Lang.Object CreateItem(int i)
        {
            return _items[i];
        }

        public override int Size()
        {
            return _items.Count();
        }

        public void AddOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
            _items.Add(overlay);
            Populate();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when I touch MapView my marker shows lower than the point I've touched.
I've thought that it may be caused my the fact that my MapView doesn't take full screen.
When I deleted ListView so that MapView could occupy whole screen, I was able to put a marker in exact point I've touched on the screen.

Any suggestions or examples about how to handle touch events if MapView takes only part of the screen?

**UPD** Found some kind of a workaround, still need to test it with different screen sizes

Convert touch coordinates

```
public static Point ConvertCoordinates(Context context, MapView mapView, double x, double y)
        {
            var wm = context.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
            var display = wm.DefaultDisplay;

            double diffY = (Convert.ToDouble(display.Height) / 2 - Convert.ToDouble(mapView.Height) / 2) / 2 - 20;
            double diffX = Convert.ToDouble(display.Width) / 2 - Convert.ToDouble(mapView.Width) / 2;

            Point size = new Point();
            size.X = (int)(x - diffX);
            size.Y = (int)(y - diffY);

            return size;
        }
```

Use it like this

```
var point = MapHelper.ConvertCoordinates(this.Context, this, e.GetX(), e.GetY());

GeoPoint longpressLocation = Projection.FromPixels(point.X, point.Y);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the reason of the problem.

This part was wrong, because **Projection** was accessed inside the **Elapsed** delegate. But by that time Projection has already changed its state, which resulted in wrong coordinates.

```
if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
    // Finger has touched screen.
    longpressTimer = new Timer(LONGPRESS_THRESHOLD);
    longpressTimer.AutoReset = false;
    longpressTimer.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e_elapsed) {
        GeoPoint longpressLocation = Projection.FromPixels((int)e.GetX(), (int)e.GetY());
        if (OnLongPress != null) {
             OnMapViewLongPressEventArgs args = new OnMapViewLongPressEventArgs();
             args.location = longpressLocation;
             OnLongPress(this, args);
        }
    };

    longpressTimer.Start();

    lastMapCenter = MapCenter;
}
```

So the solution is to get **GeoPoint** at the very beginning of **OnTouchEvent**.

```
if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
    capturedProjection = Projection.FromPixels((int)e.GetX(), (int)e.GetY());

    // Finger has touched screen.
    longpressTimer = new Timer(LONGPRESS_THRESHOLD);
    longpressTimer.AutoReset = false;
    longpressTimer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e_timer) => {
        if (OnLongPress != null) {
            OnMapViewLongPressEventArgs args = new OnMapViewLongPressEventArgs();
            args.location = capturedProjection;
            OnLongPress(this, args);
        }
    };

    longpressTimer.Start();

    lastMapCenter = MapCenter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
public PinOverlay(Drawable pin, Context context) 
    : base(BoundCenterBottom(pin))
```

This will make the `Drawable` you put on the map center on the point, rather than having the geo coordinate as the (x,y)(0,0) coordinate when it is drawn.

**EDIT:**
I can't seem to recreate your problem here, when having BoundCenterBottom(pin) in the `:base()` of the constructor it centers my `Drawable` just fine.

Also I noticed in your `AddPinToMap` method, you create a new `PinOverlay` each time. This should not be necessary and you should just add new `OverlayItem`s to the `PinOverlay` which you add only 1 time to the map. This is more efficient and less resource intensive if you are going to add a lot of pins to the map.

So it should look more like:

```
protected void AddPinToMap(GeoPoint location, string title, bool scrollTo, int zoom)
{
    var pin = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.maps_pin);
    OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(location, title, "");
    pinOverlay.AddOverlay(item); // this is instantiated in OnCreate

    if (scrollTo) {
        mapView.Controller.AnimateTo(location);
    }

    mapView.Controller.SetZoom(zoom);
}
```

And add a `Remove` method to `PinOverlay` if you want to be able to remove `OverlayItems` as well.

Also `MapView` already has a `LongClick` event, which you could hook into instead of overriding the class:

```
var mapView = FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.myMapView);
mapView.LongClick += (sender, args) => { //do whatever in here };
```

or

```
var mapView = FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.myMapView);
mapView.LongClick += OnLongClick;

private void OnLongClick(object sender, LongClickEventArgs longClickEventArgs)
{
    // do whatever in here
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this way, but it makes no difference. Even if I set Bounds explicitly, it only affects the position of the marker's shadow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about PinOverlay.

Comment: Also, I couldn't find how to get XY from LongClickEventArgs, that's why I'm using timers and touch event.